# How to efficiently search/replace on a large txt file?

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005, perl, csv, grep

I have a relatively large csv/text data file (33mb) that I need to do a global search and replace the delimiting character on. (The reason is that there doesn't seem to be a way to get SQLServer to escape/handle double quotes in the data during a table export, but that's another story...)

I successfully accomplished a Textmate search and replace on a smaller file, but it's choking on this larger file.

It seems like command line grep may be the answer, but I can't quite grasp the syntax, ala:

```
grep -rl OLDSTRING . | xargs perl -pi~ -e ‘s/OLDSTRING/NEWSTRING/’
```

So in my case I'm searching for the '^' (caret) character and replacing with '"' (double-quote).

```
grep -rl " grep_test.txt | xargs perl -pi~ -e 's/"/^'
```

That doesn't work and I'm assuming it has to do with the escaping of the doublequote or something, but I'm pretty lost. Help anyone?

*(I suppose if anyone knows how to get SQLServer2005 to handle double quotes in a text column during export to csv, that'd really solve the core issue.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your perl substitution seems to be wrong. Try:

```
grep -rl \" . | xargs perl -pi~ -e 's/\^/"/g'
```

Explanation:

```
grep : command to find matches
-r : to recursively search
-l : to print only the file names where match is found
\" : we need to escape " as its a shell meta char
. : do the search in current working dir
perl : used here to do the inplace replacement
-i~ : to do the replacement inplace and create a backup file with extension ~
-p : to print each line after replacement
-e : one line program
\^ : we need to escape caret as its a regex meta char to mean start anchor
```

Comment: That both worked and helped explain it clearly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, ok I didn't have enough 'points' to do that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i.bak 's/\^/"/g' mylargefile.csv
```

Update: you can also use Perl as rein has suggested

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\^/"/g' mylargefile.csv
```

But on big files, sed may run a bit faster than Perl, as my result shows on a 6million line file

```
$ tail -4 file
this is a line with ^
this is a line with ^
this is a line with ^

$ wc -l<file
6136650

$ time sed 's/\^/"/g' file  >/dev/null

real    0m14.210s
user    0m12.986s
sys     0m0.323s
$ time perl  -pe 's/\^/"/g' file >/dev/null

real    0m23.993s
user    0m22.608s
sys     0m0.630s
$ time sed 's/\^/"/g' file  >/dev/null

real    0m13.598s
user    0m12.680s
sys     0m0.362s

$ time perl  -pe 's/\^/"/g' file >/dev/null

real    0m23.690s
user    0m22.502s
sys     0m0.393s
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never used sed, but if it's that concise it must be worth looking at. :)